# How to join two tables if there are two columns with the same values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

[image]

Can I somehow create the resulting table in SQL?

Comment: You forgot your attempt at solving this.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional `join` key to avoid a Cartesian product.  You can generate one using `row_number()`:

```
select t1.*, t2.column4
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column1 order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 left join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column3 order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.column1 = t2.column3 and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so the last column can be in an arbitrary order for the matching initial columns.